# hibernate validation on server startup does not check column length

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(2000)")
    private String myField;

    public String getMyField() {
        return myField;
    }

    public void setMyField(String myField) {
        this.myField = myField;
    }
}
```

And i configured Hibernate to perform validation on my schema:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

And in my schema i have the column "myField" under table "my_entity" 
with max length of **255 CHAR**

I would expect Hibernate to fail on validation when server starts
because the length of the field defined in the entity is bigger than what
is defined in my schema.

Is it a bug?
Is there a way to configure Hibernate to do it?

Comment: I think you are looking for `@Column(length = 2000)`.

Comment: @Marvin I think it's the same as @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(2000)").

Anyway,  Hibernate does not perform the validation with @Column(length = 2000) either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hibernate Documentation says :

> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the
>   SessionFactory is created

Depending on the setting in which you use hibernate the SessionFactory is not
neccessarily created immediately at server startup. E.g. when you create the SessionFactory 'own your own' with `Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

**Edit** : looks a bit like it might be a Hibernate bug since [org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/org/hibernate/mapping/Table.java?av=f) only checks for the columns type.

Comment: I've verified that a session factory is created when server starts. If, for example i would a new field to the entity that does not exist on in the table, Hibernate validation will fail. So i know that Hibernate indeed performs validation, the question is why doesn't it checks that the length of the column match the length of the field it mapped to?

Comment: in that case i'm sorry i have no solution :-( ... btw. i've found a Hibernate JIRA ticket for a similar problem (not checking for 'not null' mapping definitions) which is open since 2008 ... maybe the problem you see is simply a bug in hibernate ? https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3192?jql=text%20~%20%22SchemaValidator%22
This also mentions that method 'validateColumns' in Hibernate Class org.hibernate.mapping.Table only checks for column type !

Comment: Thank you @André R,
As you mentioned it appears Hibernate does not check it when it performs
Schema validation.